# Can I add a track to an iPhone's music player from another application?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I know the answer to this is probably no, but is there any way to add an AAC file to an iPhone's music library from another application? Apple's iPod library APIs allow for an application to use tracks from the library but I can't find anything to suggest it is possible to add them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a one way process. Have a look at the [About iPod Library Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html).

> iPod library access is the iOS interface for retrieving and playing
>   items from the device iPod library. The iPod library is the set of
>   media items on a device that a user has synced from iTunes on the
>   desktop.

Short of jailbreaking the device I dont think this is possible.